# Method for finding all cubes of size L in a viewing frustum?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find or search for a method that quickly finds all cubes of size L that would be contained by a viewing frustum. Maybe even using cuda.

I have made a DDA traversal for raycasting, which is like a 1D case to me and simple, as I only move along the line at a known distance.

My instinct was to create a bounding box of the frustum, and subdivide this space into a spatial grid of size L cubes. Then test each cell's center of the grid for being inside the frustum. Considering the frustum is a pyramid, it seems that about half the cells would be occupied by a bounding box and I feel that this method is just doing too much work. It will surely work though, I am hoping for a less naive or faster geometric approach.

Perhaps ray cast the left wall first, then right wall second and then line cast in between these? So in a nutshell, looking for the R3 version of something like a DDA traversal.

Comment: Does the entirety of the cube need to be contained inside the frustum?

Comment: Not entirely no, I consider inside to be any vertex to be inside the frustum. I am not worried about a case where a rotated cube clips the corner of a frustum bounds. My world is made up of hermite data, and thus axis aligned

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to detect if a vertex resides within a frustum is [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The frustum consists of 4 planes, that is top, bottom, left, right, and two z values, front and back clipping. For each vertex check two things: First, is it outside front or back panel? And if not, is it inside the four planes?

1. To check if a vertex is outside front or back panel you check vertex.Z against your frustrum:

   ```
   isInsideZ = vertex.Z >= frustrum.Zmin && vertex.Z <= frustrum.Zmax;
   ```
2. To check if it's inside the four frustrum 'walls' you need to compute the [cross vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) for them, oriented towards the frustrum's center. Then check the dot product of each cross vector and the position vector to your vertex relative to the respective plane. You obtain this position vector by subtracting some arbitrary point *on* the plane from the vertex you test. Should the dot product be positive, the vertex is *above* that plane.

   ```
   isAbove[i] = Vector3D.Dot(cross[i], vertex - planeloc[i]) > 0;
   ```

   Where `planeloc[i]` is *any* point located on the respective plane *i*.

The vertex is inside the frustrum if all conditions are met:

```
isInside = isInsideZ && isAbove[0] && isAbove[1] && isAbove[2] && isAbove[3];
```

This sounds a bit awkward to handle, but a lot of things can be done outside the grinding loop, such as computing the cross products, i.e. frustrum plane normals, or the plane location vectors. For example, if a plane is spanned by `(1,0,0), (1,1,0)` then `(1,0,0)` already represents a point located on that plane.

Comment: Yeah, calculating a frustum test is pretty straight forward. I am looking for a more efficient way to get a list of axis aligned bounding boxes of size L contained by a frustum. So what I do currently is to get the AABB of the frustum itself, and loop from far left to far right, far top to far bottom, using the test you suggested: IsInsideFrustum, Getting an AABB from a frustum involves projecting a normalized point on the near and far plane into the world: -1,1 or 0,1 depending on your system, Then find the min/max verts. I still feel like there might be a more direct approach. A hunch

Comment: You could calculate a 3x3 transformation matrix that would shape your frustrum into an axis aligned cube, then transform any vertex in question with it and check xmin < x < xmax resp ymin < y < ymax (z was already done before). That would be 9 mul, 6 add, 4 cmp for each vertex vs 12 mul, 12 add, 4 cmp with the dot product version. Just an idea. @JManMousey

Comment: And if the frustrum is always axis aligned with a fixed aperture angle you could calculate a skew factor so that you just check `xmin < x*xskew*z < xmax` resp `ymin < y*yskew*z < ymax`. @JManMousey